# Как в vk_api принять параметр?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

имею бота написаного на [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api)
Пытаюсь сделать реферальную систему. Прочитал [на этой странице](https://vk.com/dev/objects/message), что есть параметр ref
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне его получить через vk_api?

Код моего бота:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import vk_api
import sqlite3
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import random
import keyboards

import texts

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=айди)
vk = vk_session.get_api()



def get_user_name(user_id):
    first = vk.users.get(user_id=user_id)[0]['first_name']
    last = vk.users.get(user_id=user_id)[0]['last_name']
    text = f'{first} {last}'
    return text


for event in longpoll.listen():

    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        if event.text.lower() == 'Начать'.lower() or event.text.lower() == 'Старт'.lower() or event.text.lower() == '↪️ В главное меню ↩️'.lower() or event.text.lower() == '/start'.lower() or event.text.lower() =='Привет'.lower(): #Если написали заданную фразу
            if event.from_user:
                connection = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
                q = connection.cursor() 
                q.execute(f"SELECT userid FROM ugc_users")
                userid = q.fetchone()
                if userid == None:
                    q.execute("INSERT INTO ugc_users (userid,name) VALUES ('%s','%s')"%(event.user_id,get_user_name(event.user_id)))
                    connection.commit()
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'{texts.main_text()}' ,random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999),keyboard=keyboards.keyboard_main.get_keyboard())
                else:
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'{texts.new_user(event.from_user)}' ,random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999),keyboard=keyboards.keyboard_start.get_keyboard())





            elif event.text.lower() == '☑️'.lower(): #Если написали заданную фразу
                if event.from_user: #Если написали в ЛС
                    vk.messages.send( #Отправляем сообщение
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        message='Успешно' ,
                        random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999),
                        keyboard=keyboards.keyboard_url(event.user_id).get_keyboard())


            elif event.text.lower() == ' Информация'.lower(): #Если написали заданную фразу
                if event.from_user:
                    vk.messages.send(user_id=event.user_id,message=f'{texts.info()}',random_id=random.randint(1,99999999999999))
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в объект `event.obj.message`, например, с помощью `dir(event.obj.message)`, там должен присутствовать этот атрибут.

Либо в `event.raw`(возможно, не точно так, давно не пользовался)

`event.raw` хранит именно сам ответ, который и пришел от вк в формате `JSON`.

Его можно преобразовать в `dict` с помощью `json.loads`

Но это только если соответствующий параметр не будет в `event.obj.message`

**P.S.**

Именно в vk_api иногда сообщение будет в `event.obj`, а иногда `event.obj.message`.

[Обратите внимание](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues/336)

Answer (score 0):

По логике, при отлове сообщений, аргумент ref должен быть в объекте event.obj. Я посмотрел, его там нету, значит этот аргумент не обязательный и появляется при определённых условиях. В любом случае я думаю вам нужно смотреть это в event.obj.

> p.s. при print(event.obj.ref), принтится None

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно искать атрибуты ref и ref_source в ответе `messages.getById(message_ids=[self.event.message_id])`

У меня это выглядело следующим образом:
`self.vk.messages.getById(message_ids=[self.event.message_id], extended=1)['items'][0]['ref'])`